# firefox-os build error for note3

Tags: git, firefox, github, operating-system, samsung-mobile

Hello i have set my note 3 device up to build firefox-os but when i try to do ./config.sh note3 it says this

```
From git://github.com/burnsyboo/b2g-manifest
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
 * [new branch]      revert-203-bug1025788-v2 -> origin/revert-203-bug1025788-v2
 * [new branch]      revert-226-v1.3t -> origin/revert-226-v1.3t
 * [new branch]      revert-316-bug-1149387 -> origin/revert-316-bug-1149387
 * [new branch]      v1-train   -> origin/v1-train
 * [new branch]      v1.0.0     -> origin/v1.0.0
 * [new branch]      v1.0.1     -> origin/v1.0.1
 * [new branch]      v1.1.0hd   -> origin/v1.1.0hd
 * [new branch]      v1.2       -> origin/v1.2
 * [new branch]      v1.2f      -> origin/v1.2f
 * [new branch]      v1.3       -> origin/v1.3
 * [new branch]      v1.3t      -> origin/v1.3t
 * [new branch]      v1.4       -> origin/v1.4
 * [new branch]      v2.0       -> origin/v2.0
 * [new branch]      v2.1       -> origin/v2.1
 * [new branch]      v2.1s      -> origin/v2.1s
 * [new branch]      v2.2       -> origin/v2.2
 * [new branch]      v2.2r      -> origin/v2.2r
 * [new tag]         B2G_1_0_1_20130213094222 -> B2G_1_0_1_20130213094222
 * [new tag]         B2G_1_1_0_hd_20130530182315 -> B2G_1_1_0_hd_20130530182315
 * [new tag]         B2G_1_1_0_hd_20130530182315_BASE -> B2G_1_1_0_hd_20130530182315_BASE
 * [new tag]         closing-nightly -> closing-nightly

##### ERROR #####
fatal: manifest 'note3.xml' not available
fatal: remote github not defined in /home/android/firefox-os/b2g/.repo/manifests/note3.xml
Repo sync failed
```

I have checked and checked and checked and everything I have done looks correct, but it keeps throwing this error at me.